# Code format rules

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I found that I can apply code formatting rules by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Visual C++. But how to edit these rules?

I need somehow define this rule:

transform 
**from:**

```
if (i=1) {do_something;}
```

**to:**

```
if (i=1) 
   {
   do_something;
   }
```

Where and how I can setup this?

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting. I don't believe you can define arbitrary rules - you can just tweak the options of built-in formatting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

To get

```
if (i=1) 
   {
   do_something;
   }
```

(which I find rather unconventional) you need to indent braces

[image: Indent braces]

and move control blocks to a new line

[image: Move to new line]

(Screenshots from Visual Studio 2013. I hope Visual Studio 2010 has the same settings.)